# how start elasticsearch in ubuntu which not terminate after closing terminal session?

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04

i started **elasticsearch** by running `./bin/elasticsearch` it work fine but after closing terminal my **elasticsearch** went down. any one could say me how to run it that **elasticsearch**  don't down soon ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `./bin/elasticsearch -d` to run Elasticsearch in daemon mode.